# Docker Swarm and clustering usage

Tags: docker, containers, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

I have a few tasks running in containers, which works as usual, and just stacks.  Now I want to add a few machines, for the same tasks. What I'm trying to achieve, it's some kind of `Executors` and active node pool, where all other tasks queue up.

*What I have tried so far, it's just single `Docker` `Container` of `Jenkins`, where we can add new worker machines, and execute usual tasks. Where `Jenkins` will manage load balancing during work. Nothing special here.*

We also have `Docker` `Swarm`, for  **Container Orchestration**, which in my understanding, should do the same - Manage `Containers` (and tasks). And from the Documentation, there is only one task for the `Swarm` it's managing scale and load balancing on the Server(by splitting traffic between working nodes).

1) Is it possible (and how) to create `Docker` `Swarm` cluster as `Executor` of the active machine, and submit other `Containers`(a task) to it, so `Swarm` will manage on which node should it start execution. If no, what is the right solution for such a task (container task submission)?

2) What is the other(maybe few of them) purposes of `Docker` `Swarm`, besides managing scale and load balancing (describing in the Doc)? Because general documentation, has example only for scaling `Web Application`?

Comment: It is possible that you are not getting any answers here because this is not programming. In particular we use `this style` for code, whereas your question appears just to use it to emphasize words that are not instructions in a programming language. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting